# Validate Excel Data via Web Service or connecting to SQL Server

Tags: c#, excel, web-services

I want to provide my users with an Excel template where they are suppose to enter specific data into certain cells.  How do I setup the spreadsheet so it validates the values they enter against a Web Service, so that they are only permitted to enter valid values?

**Updated:**
i provide my users with an excel(generated through C# code) which has following columns ("Username" , "First Name" , "Middle Name", "Last Name", "Contact" , "Email".. etc).

Currently what i do is i ask them to upload that excel, once they upload i traverse through that excel and validate the data against my database :
For example :entered User Name , contact and email should be unique and should not exist in my database.. and so on.If entered data is valid I update the same in my database else prompt message  "validation error".

My question is : Is there any way i can generate an Excel template through C#  which should be connected to my Azure SQL database and i should be able to validate user's input corresponding to each column like "Username" ,"Contact" and so on at the very point they enter it ....so that i can skip validation process later ...because this will be more user friendly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reworded to explain the need, and ask a clear answerable question.

Comment: i provide my users with an excel(generated through code) which has following columns ("Username" , "First Name" , "Middle Name", "Last Name", "Contact" , "Email".. etc). Currently what i do is i ask them to upload that excel, once they upload i traverse through that excel and validate the data against my database :
For example :entered UserName , contact and email should be unique and should be exist in my database.